# paypal post request for approve the payment

Tags: laravel, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I have paypal express checkout in my laravel project. I'm using client side rest and after having execute the payment, in actions.payment.execute() I am making requets, getting access_token with https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token url.

Then I'm trying to make curl reuqest to confirm the payment:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/". $PaymentID . "/execute"
```

But I get PERMISSION_DENIED from curl request:

```
 "No permission for the requested operation"
```

This is my curl request

```
$ch = curl_init();
    $token = $arrData['AccessToken'];
    $data = ['payer_id' => $arrData['PayerID']];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/". $arrData['PaymentID'] ."/execute");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
                          "Content-Type:application/json",
                          "Authorization:Bearer ".$token )
            );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result, TRUE); // 'true' converts it to an array
    var_dump($json);exit;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Maybe anybody had same issue and know what is the reason?

Or maybe in client side rest we dont need to make curl request to approve the payment. I'm not sure if   onAuthorize function is enough to approve the payment.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a PayPal app setup, if so, you may not have the correct permissions set there.

Comment: I have sandbox account for local tests. Do I need to add any permissions?

Comment: Could be that, or it could be they don't allow posting payments through the sandbox like that. I know Authorize.net is restrictive about what you can run through their payment gayway, I can only assume PayPal is similar.

Comment: I have not see anything in their docs, that using sandbox we can't make post approval request.

Comment: I don't work with PayPal services to know for sure. I would dig around on their end though and see if there is something permission related preventing this from going through. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Lusine Martirosyan, I think you don't need a curl request if you use client side rest.
Refer to this link https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Change 3 information if needed; env
Client.sandbox or client.prod if necessary, between the id of your application created on your dev account of paypal.
It works for me in sandbox

Comment: enter id  of your application, sorry i use a translator